# Ubuntu 20.04 64bits - Unknown CMake command "ament_auto_find_test_dependencies"

Tags: ubuntu

this project builds fine on a rapsberry pi 4

```
https://github.com/fmrico/book_ros2
```

Now I try to build this on a virtual box VM using this image

ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso

I have been installing any package conceivable, yet this does not build

```
phil@ROS2:~/WORK/bookros2_ws$ colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> launch_pal
Finished <<< launch_pal [4.17s]           
Starting >>> pmb2_controller_configuration
Finished <<< pmb2_controller_configuration [5.45s]                    
Starting >>> pal_gripper_controller_configuration
Finished <<< pal_gripper_controller_configuration [4.27s]                    
Starting >>> pmb2_laser_sensors
--- stderr: pmb2_laser_sensors                           
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (ament_auto_find_test_dependencies):
  Unknown CMake command "ament_auto_find_test_dependencies".


---
Failed   <<< pmb2_laser_sensors [3.63s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 3 packages finished [18.0s]
  1 package failed: pmb2_laser_sensors
  1 package had stderr output: pmb2_laser_sensors
  33 packages not processed
```

thanks for your help

[edit]

```
phil@ROS2:~/WORK/bookros2_ws$ cat /home/phil/WORK/bookros2_ws/src/ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_laser_sensors/CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(pmb2_laser_sensors)

find_package(ament_cmake_auto REQUIRED)
ament_auto_find_build_dependencies()

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  ament_auto_find_test_dependencies()
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_auto_package(INSTALL_TO_SHARE config launch)
```

Comment: You should also post your CMakeLists.txt file for the `pmb2_laser_sensors` package. This will help us understand the source of the error

Comment: yeah, I finaly found the file to have a look to, I modded my question. now I am trying to find the file where that function should be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something works on one machine but not the other, it's generally a configuiration/versioning issue. It appears that `ament_auto_find_test_dependencies` wasn't added until [two years ago (check the git blame)](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blame/65b1754af10bb1f8d23f33d68ef6f41c0bce5376/ament_cmake_auto/ament_cmake_auto-extras.cmake#L24), so if you're on 20.04, it's likely that the "unknown CMake command" is because that command simply doesn't exist on your 20.04 computer.

You can try these three things:

- Upgrading CMake, Catkin, Ament, and whatever else in the build chain
- Using [CMake's `if` statement](https://www.devdoc.net/linux/cmake-3.9.6/command/if.html), which can be used to check if a command/macro is available, to first check if testing can be performed using that command before attempting it
- Both of the above, to maximize both your environment and portability of your project.

Comment: I commented these 4 lines around that BUILD_TESTING, and now I get other issues.